# 1st ViewController in Portrait and SecondViewController in Landscape Mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

My requirement is this my 1st viewcontroller open in Portrait mode only.and when user goes to 2nd viewcontroller i want that controller in Landscape mode how may i do this

i tried this code

1st ViewController.m

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    returnc YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;

}
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interface
{

    return (interface==UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait);
}
```

Code for 2nd ViewController.m

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;

    //return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}




- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}
```

this will not working fine for me.

Comment: What's not working about it?  Describe the problem you are having.

Comment: when user going to second controller displays in protrait mode i want it in landscape mode

Comment: I answered similar question, it can help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18185260/view-controllers-in-view-controller-and-orientation-ios/18185775#18185775

Comment: how can i do this i know the way to create the category but which code write it....

Comment: check my sample demo https://www.dropbox.com/s/lrsz4dpeolpeu23/RotationDmeo.zip

Comment: @Kalpesh thanks i get the proper idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am solving my problem using Category....
Add new files and select Category and make subclass UINavigationController class.

here is the code for category for .h

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "AppDelegate.h"

    @interface UINavigationController (orientation)

    @end

code for .m file

#import "UINavigationController+orientation.h"

@implementation UINavigationController (orientation)

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{

    AppDelegate * delegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    if (delegate.islandscape)
    {
        // for iPhone, you could also return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;

    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;

}
@end
```

isLandscape is declared in App delegate to check weather First view controller or secondView Controller isLandscape is Bool.

Now FirstViewController.m file i want that in Portarit mode so used this code

```
- (IBAction)PlayClicked:(id)sender
{
    AppDelegate * delegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];


    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=YES;
    delegate.islandscape=YES;

    ViewController * v=[[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self presentViewController:v animated:NO completion:nil];


    //[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:v animated:YES];

}


- (NSInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

and SecondViewController i want that in Landscape mode used this one.

```
delegate.islandscape=NO;   // called transfer to Category 

- (NSInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation);
}
```

**UPDATED:**

You can do this by creating category of UINaviagationController

code for .h file is

```
@interface UINavigationController (autorotation)

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate;
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations;
```

and code for .m file is

```
 @implementation UINavigationController (autorotation)

    -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
    {

        UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
        [self.topViewController shouldAutorotate];
        return YES;

    }

    -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;

    }
    @end
```

Comment: this code is for category so how may i appley this on my firstview and secondview...

Comment: you can use it by using your UINavigation class instance to call above method.

Answer (score 0):

paste following code in viewcontroller .m file of second view controller (under @implementation section)

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}
```

Now select the second view controller in storyboard (Selection indicated by blue border around view controller), go to the attribute inspector (right side 'shield' like image) change the orientation to landscape.. That's it.. .Tell me if it doesn't work for u. ..:)